# How to unset an array by null key in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, key, unset

Before:

```
$my_array = Array ( [TRUE] => 1 [FALSE] => 2 [] => 0 )
```

I wanna remove the array if the key[] is null.

My concept :

```
if ($my_array.key is null) {
    unset($my_array.key)
}
```

Hope the array becomes:

```
$my_array = Array ( [TRUE] => 1 [FALSE] => 2)
```

Comment: Did your concept work?

Comment: FYI: You can take tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works and where everything is.

Comment: @carinhere *it doesn't work* What do you mean with this? Your concept? (Also if you want to write something to someone use: `@username`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unset it just [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) it out like this:

```
<?php

    $my_array = [TRUE => 1, FALSE => 2, NULL => 0]; 
    print_r($my_array);
    $my_array = array_filter($my_array, "strlen", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    print_r($my_array); 

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [0] => 2 [] => 0 )
Array ( [1] => 1 [0] => 2 )
```

**Side Note:**

A key can't actually be NULL. You can also see this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The **key** can either be an **integer or a string**. The value can be of any type.

Means your "NULL" key gets casted to an empty string. You can see this with a `var_dump()`:

```
array(3) { [1]=> int(1) [0]=> int(2) [""]=> int(5) }
                                   //^^^^ See the key is just an empty string
```